# Finding web element using Java/selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

HTML CODE

```
input class="btn primary" onclick="return login_jsp.saveRemember &amp;&amp; login_jsp.saveRemember() || true;" 
type="submit" value="Sign In"
```

Following approaches did not help :

1)

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn primary")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).click();
```

2)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='btn primary']")).click();
```

(OR)

1)

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn primary")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

2)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='btn primary']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.primary")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

See Sendkeys and Click won't work together.
So if there is some text field you can enter value there by :

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn primary")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

and then you if need to click some button or link you can use Click() as:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='btn primary']")).click();
```

Note: You should take the xpath of the same, to perform either sendkeys() or click()

Reply back to me if you have further query.
Happy learning:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below locators

> Css Selector
>
> input[value='Sign In']
>
> input.btn.primary
>
> xpath
>
> //input[@value='Sign In']
>
> //input[@class='btn primary']

please make use that above ones fetching specific element or not, may be by using firepath before using in webdriver script.

If you want to simulate ENTER then go for sendkeys with key events. If you want to just click on element then just use click();

this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) helps you to write css selectors and this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) you on xpath

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

```
input class="btn primary" onclick="return login_jsp.saveRemember &amp;&amp; login_jsp.saveRemember() || true;" 
type="submit" value="Sign In"
```

try below approches

```
1. driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn primary")).click();
2. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click();
3. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']").click();
3. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[text()='Sign In']").click();
```